# PS command column display full detail

Tags: ps, mks

Whilst signed on a server as "sa_brett", if I open a CMD window as an administrator (right click and run as administrator) and then type:

C:> ps -ef |grep ORACLE.EXE

I get the following:

SYSTEM   8828    644  0 07:05:06 con 57:38 d:\oracle\11.2.0.3\bin\ORACLE.EXE LIVE

SYSTEM   8288    644  0 07:05:38 con  0:13 d:\oracle\11.2.0.3\bin\ORACLE.EXE TEST

sa_brett  11736  10532  0 09:42:57 con  0:00 grep  ORACLE.EXE

However, if I open a CMD window (not as administrator and type) the same command as above I only get my "grep" command returned

C:>ps -ef |grep ORACLE.EXE

sa_brett  12852  11364  0 10:24:16 con  0:00 grep  ORACLE.EXE

If I change the search to lower case "oracle" then I now get results, but I don't get the full command for oracle i.e. ORACLE.EXE LIVE or ORACLE.EXE TEST (which is what I need)

C:\Windows>ps -ef |grep oracle
       0   8828      1  0 07:05:06 con  1h25 oracle

```
   0   8288      1  0 07:05:38 con  0:16 oracle
```

sa_brett  12300  11364  0 10:24:21 con  0:00 grep  oracle

I want to write a script which detects the "LIVE" or "TEST" but because the PS command isn't returning the full detail it's not working.

Any advise greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create your script, make a shortcut to the script, right-click shortcut > Properties > Advanced > Run As Administrator, then click OK.  Call your script via the shortcut for it.  It will run as Administrator, and you'll get the PS output you need for your script every time.

Hope this helps!